# Confusion about Hartshorne 5.16.1

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme over a Noetherian scheme $Y$. This remark claims:

> $X$ is projective over $Y$ if and and only if $X$ is proper over $Y$ and there exists an invertible very ample sheaf $\mathscr{L}$ on $X$.

Projectivity implies these two condistions seems to be clear. For the other direction, it cites an exercise before:

> $f:X\to Z$ separated and of finite type over Noetherian $Y$, then any closed subscheme $C$  of $X$ which is proper over $Y$ has image $f(C)$ (with induced image subscheme structure) proper over $Y$.

In this case, $Z=\mathbb{P}^n_Y$ and $i:X\hookrightarrow Z$ an given immersion. Then $X,Z$ are both separated and of finite type over $Y$. Take $C=X$. Then we see the image closed. Then $i$ is a closed immersion, so $f$ is projective. Somehow, I do not need the existence of this invertible sheaf $\mathscr{L}$. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very ample invertible sheaf $\mathcal{L}$ is how you get the immersion $X\to \Bbb P^n_Y$: Hartshorne's *definition* of a very ample sheaf $\mathcal{L}$ relative to a morphism $X\to Y$ is one so that $\mathcal{L}$ is $i^*\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^n_Y}(1)$ for some immersion $i:X\to \Bbb P^n_Y$. In general, there is no reason for a scheme $X$ over $Y$ to have an immersion to $\Bbb P^n_Y$: see for instance exercise II.7.13, where a proper scheme over $k$ with no immersion in to $\Bbb P^n_k$ is constructed.

Comment: I see, so the proposition can be stated as "projective if and only if proper and there exists an immersion to the projective space". But just the existence of the immersion is "useless", we need the invertible sheaf to produce the projective morphism?

Comment: @CO2 Your first sentence is correct, but your second is a bit confused. If there's an immersion $i:X\to\Bbb P^n_Y$, then $i^*\mathcal{O}(1)$ is a very ample invertible sheaf on $X$ relative to $Y$.